# Elixir lang processing lists in parallel

Tags: elixir

I'm currently having an issue processing lists in elixir in parallel. The reason for the parallelism is that I'm saving the results to an API and if I blast them all at once it gets DDOS'd and shuts down.

The code below is supposed to split the result of a `SQL` query and process each row in a separate task and when all the tasks have been completed, it should terminate.

What happens is that the first task, after firing a message, causes the script to terminate. I've seen answers where they put the receive in a function and that function calls itself over and over but I feel like there has to be another better way to handle this.

```
results = Enum.chunk(results, 500)

# Give this process a name
Process.register(self(), :core)

# Loop over the chunks making a process for each
Enum.each results, fn(result) ->
  task = Task.async(fn -> Person.App.process(result, "Test", "1") end)
end

# And listen for messages
receive do
  {:hello, msg} -> IO.inspect msg
  {:world, _} -> "won't match"
end
```

Comment: This code no longer compiles

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using `Task.async` it is most convenient to obtain the result with `Task.await`:

```
results
|> Enum.map(fn result -> Task.async(fn -> Person.App.process(result, "Test", "1") end) end)
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
|> Enum.each(&IO.inspect/1)
```

In fact if you don't `await` for the result of `async` it will still be sent to the process that called `async` and stored in its mailbox, potentially causing a memory leak! If your intention is to create a `Task` where you don't care about the result use `Task.start` or `Task.start_link` instead.

Comment: When I change the Task.async to Task.start_link the main process exits before the rows finish processing. How do I keep the script alive until all the Tasks have finished?

Comment: I think you should use the method in the answer - keep using `Task.async` and then `Task.await` for all the tasks (that's what `Enum.map(&Task.await/1)` does). The result of that line will be all the results of the tasks gathered in a list - you can then print them out (`Enum.each(&IO.inspect/1)` in the answer) or do something else with them.

Comment: Ok cool that worked for me! I had to change the task await to take in a timeout though since sometimes the tasks take 10-20 seconds Enum.map(&Task.await(&1, 20000))

Comment: Right, the default timeout is 5000 (5 secs)